# Managing Projects With SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Just a general question about Project Management on 2010 Enterprise. 
Does this version come with a project template as the only one thats available is 'Project Web Database' ?

Does anyone know of a good resource showing how to build an ootb Project management system?

Thanks

Comment: Since you already have the enterprise license, have you considered getting Project Server?

Comment: Project Server may be an overkill at this stage. Someone must have developed an ootb solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are some books specialized for 2010 project management. Take a look at this:

[http://www.amazon.com/SharePoint-2010-Project-Management-Raymond/dp/1449306373](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449306373)